# Read data from dynamic table Django

Tags: django, django-orm

I have automated batch process which creates tables in SQLite DB and update the new created table name in one of the tables defined by Django ORM.

I would like to know how can I use Django ORM to select data from newly created table?

Comment: So what's the question?

Comment: @user20223018 How to retrieve data from this new table based on table name retrieved from on the Django ORM table?

Comment: You're going to have to give some more details then just "Get data from table using ORM". Give what you've already tried or what you're trying to do with some code